# Trigger to Update value in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with coming up with the correct statement to update a field in the same table as an insert trigger. It is for an MySql table.

Basically I need the inserted value to be checked for a base color in the field, so if the field is: 'Cobalt Blue', i want the color to be inserted into the field to be 'Blue'.

I already came up with the following statement to get the correct color to be correctly:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN 'value' LIKE '%blue%' THEN 'Blue'
    WHEN 'value' LIKE '%red%' THEN 'Red'
    ELSE 'Other color'
END AS normalized_color
FROM 'products_extra_fields'
WHERE 'products_extra_fields'.'value' = 'color'
```

Now next I need this to be in a trigger on the table insert WHERE 'products_extra_fields'.'value' = 'color'.

I just cannot seem to figure out how to build this trigger to contain an UPDATE with the SELECT CASE statement.

Comment: How can your value be `= 'color'` and `LIKE '%red%'` at the same time ? This query will always return 'Other color'.

Comment: The value 'color' is only the name of the field in the 'products_extra_fields' table. This is done because the table contains a record for every extra field added to the product table. This might be confusing, but the query acutally works I get a nice list of all colors corrected, just tested it again.

Comment: Um.. ok.. which field has field name and which has the value ?

Comment: The table has the following structure: id, productId, name, value. The first record is: 1, 1, color, red. Second record could be: 2, 1, size,  large 3rd rec: 3, 2, color, blue etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to update the table after inserting, you can just change the value to be inserted in the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_products_extra_fields` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `products_extra_fields` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.name = 'color') THEN
        SET NEW.value = CASE 
            WHEN NEW.value LIKE '%red%' THEN 'red'
            WHEN NEW.value LIKE '%blue%' THEN 'blue'
            ...
            ELSE 'other'
        END;
    END IF;
END
```

Also you should probably create a similar `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on that table.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for. However I get an error when importing this statement. phpMyAdmin says it is in the line: END; (just after the ELSE). 
I think this has to do with a BEGIN missing??

Comment: I eventually fixed this by creating a trigger in phpMyAdmin manually. This worked, so the statement itself was correct! Thanks.